# Get element value on different pages using same class name

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm using an element value with the default loaded page:
like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="environment_1" class="myView">
```

And later, I'm loading another page like:

```
$("#myContent").load("newPage");
```

Inside this new page I have a similar html tag:

```
<input type="hidden" value="environment_2" class="myView">
```

My problem is that after the load, if I do :

```
myEnv = $('.myView').val();
alert (myEnv);
```

It always show me `environment_1` value. How could I get the new `environment_2` value ?

Comment: You could use: `$('input[value="environment_2"]').val();` or `$('.myView').last().val();` - [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) doc page.

Comment: is `<input type="hidden" value="environment_1" class="myView">` iside the element `#myContent`

Comment: is the first input inside the #myContent ? If not, the last call will find the last myView

Comment: What does *"after the load"* mean? **When** exactly are calling `$('.myView').val();`? Please post a more complete example, showing the relation between the `.load` and the `.val` call.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think you're onto something. `#myContent` contains `environment_1` and is then overwritten with new content containing `environment_2`, and `myEnv` is set after the `load` call has been made and is expected to reference `environment_2` but doesn't, for synchronicity reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always look for the first element's `val`

type

```
myEnv = $('.myView:last').val();
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fGVhg/)

Comment: @Zamboo: You really should update your question and add additional information (i.e. answer all the questions that have been asked in the comments). Otherwise I doubt the question is going to be very helpful for someone else because it is difficult to figure out what the problem actually is. All the answers here are just educated guesses.

Answer (score 2):

`.load` is **asynchronous**. I assume you are calling `$('.myView').val();` *before* the content was changed.

Make sure you call `.val` only after the content was changed. You can do this by passing a callback to `.load`:

```
$("#myContent").load("newPage", function() {
    alert($('.myView').val());
});
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted. From the clues in the question, I would never have figured out that that's what was being asked :)

Comment: Well, it is just a hunch. It could also be that `.val` is indeed called after the content changed (e.g. through an event handler). At this stage it's just a guess, like all the others.

Answer (score 1):

When a selector yields more than one element, `.val` will always yield the value of the *first* element in the set.

In order to target `environment_2` you need to be more specific about which element you're querying. Should you be looking specifically at `$('#myContent .myView')`? Or perhaps always at `$('.myView:last')`?

If you want all values, you could do:

```
$('.myView').map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
```

jQuery doesn't know exactly what you want for the same reasons that we don't :)

Answer (score 1):

use 
`$('.myView')[0].value`

and

`$('.myView')[1].value`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you check `$('.myView').length` . It should return 2.

then you can write code

```
$('.myView:last').val();
```

OR

```
$('.myView').last().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have two elements with class `myView` in the page now (I'm assuming that the first myView is not inside the element `#myContent`).

This will cause `$('.myView')` to return 2 elements and `$('.myView').val()` will return the value of the first element.

One solution is to look for the `myView` inside `myContent` in the second search like

```
$('.myView', '#myContent').val()
```